# Connecting ArcMap to secure folder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, connection

I am accessing data from a National Data Services secure server. Within the server, all my project data is in one folder, and applications like ArcMap are in a separate folder.

In ArcMap, "add data" will connect to the drive (M:), but the secure folder is not listed as being there.

I had a similar problem with accessing Stata commands, and that was solved by adding "adopath +" at the beginning of every do file, to specify the directory were the commands are listed.

I think I need to direct ArcMap to this secure folder, in a more technical way, than just using "add data", but I have no idea how, I can't find the answer online, and technical support at the data service has provided no assistance.

As it's a secure server, I cannot add snapshots of the problem here.

Comment: This is probably an issue for Tech Support. Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact release of Desktop in use (the tagged 10.0 is long, long retired, and unsuitable for new storage technology)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't understand what you mean, it is 10.0, I verified that in the about section on GIS, the data service hasn't updated it, and they don't provide software specific assistance. Hence my dilemma.However, if updating the software helps with this issue, then this is something I could ask the data service to do.

Comment: 10.0 had five major service packs and two score of significant patches before it was retired from support nearly five years ago. It is not compatible with any modern operating system, and certainly shouldn't be used with any storage solution that claims to be "secure".

Comment: Ah thank you very much for this! The data service is quite poor to be honest, so this doesn't surprise me that they have neglected software updates. I will email them and request a software update.